# Invalid Date with moment js in a date picker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, momentjs, antdv

I try to display a date in a date picker (use AntDesign with VueJS) :

```js
this.formDates.test = moment(this.$store.state.dataStudy.startPassation).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
```

When I do this I have my date with the correct format :

```js
console.log(this.formDates.test) // display the correct format 05-07-2021 12:00
```

But when I do this :

```html
<a-date-picker :default-value="formDates.test" v-model="formDates.startPassation" /><!-- display Invalid Date-->
```

I have "Invalid Date" in my date picker :-(

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.antdv.com/components/date-picker/) I see that is possible to set `:default-value` with a moment object.

```
<a-date-picker :defaultValue="moment('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')" />
```

try to remove `.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')`

Comment: Thanks ! I thought I had tested this but indeed it works!